# Deploy WebGL applications as native iOS or Android applications?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, webgl

Does anyone know of a way in which you can deploy a WebGL app as a native iOS or Android app?  Commercial middleware is acceptable, although an open project would be preferable.  Thanks.

Comment: I really want to enable WebGL + PhoneGap. That'd be cool. I think its possible to take Android's current WebView code and add WebGL to it, and create a substitute WebGL WebView for use with PhoneGap. I'm not sure about iPhone though, since they aren't open source unfortunately. :/ ... It'll just have to be a matter of time before they decide to include WebGL (which will be later than sooner so as to not reduce the sales of apps in their iStore).

Answer (score 24):

As an extension to Joris' answer (which appears to be based on the [work of Nathan de Vries](http://atnan.com/blog/2011/11/03/enabling-and-using-webgl-on-ios/)), the following is the code I needed to enable WebGL within the iOS 5.0 SDK:

Somewhere near the top of your view controller implementation:

```
@interface UIWebView()
- (void)_setWebGLEnabled:(BOOL)newValue;
@end
```

Programmatically creating a UIWebView and enabling WebGL:

```
UIWebView *webDetailView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:mainScreenFrame];

id webDocumentView = [webDetailView performSelector:@selector(_browserView)];
id backingWebView = [webDocumentView performSelector:@selector(webView)];
[backingWebView _setWebGLEnabled:YES];
```

I [created a sample application](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/WebGLTester.zip) that demonstrates WebGL running in a iPhone / iPad fullscreen UIWebView, using the WebGL scratchpad site http://glsl.heroku.com as a destination. Be wary that some of those examples there will grind even an iPad 2 to a halt, potentially leading to a hard reboot. The performance there seems to indicate why WebGL is still in an officially unsupported state in mobile WebKit.

Of course, as has been stated, this is not guaranteed to work on future iOS versions and will get your application rejected from the App Store. This is only really useful for hobby work and internal testing.

An example of WebGL running on my iPad 2:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seems to work at all. the project doesn't run on my device at all.

Comment: @ItayLevin - This was for older iOS versions. WebGL has been officially supported in UIWebView since iOS 8 (although you'll probably want to use WKWebView for performance). This was a hack to get it to run on older iOS versions, in case people needed that.

Answer (score 6):

WebKit on iOS actually supports WebGL, as of 4.x (not sure which .x version). It is enabled in the webview used by the iAd framework, all other uses of WebKit (Safari and UIWebView) have WebGL disabled.

It is possible to enable WebGL using private API's (this will not pass the submission process). In your webview subclass:

```
- (void)setWebGLEnabled:(BOOL)enableWebGL {
    UIWebDocumentView* webDocumentView = [self _browserView];
    WebView* backingWebView = [webDocumentView webView];
    [backingWebView _setWebGLEnabled:enableWebGL];
}
```

([via](http://atnan.com/blog/2011/11/03/enabling-and-using-webgl-on-ios/))

This will at least allow you to start experimenting with WebGL on iOS.

Not sure about WebGL support on Android. Fairly [recent comments on the issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11012) in the Android tracker suggest it is not available yet.

A nice support table for WebGL in (mobile) browsers: [When can I use WebGL](http://caniuse.com/webgl)

Best way to go for now seems to be to include your own WebGL enabled version of WebKit in your application wrapper for both iOS and Android.

Comment: WebGL seems to run with Firefox Mobile Browser on Android Devices (at least some): http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=4379.

Comment: You could probably use some KVC to make this a lot easier. ;)

Answer (score 1):

As the iOS version of WebKit doesn't support WebGL natively, I think you have two options:

- Implement the WebGL API in the JavaScript context of a WebView yourself by forwarding calls to the native OpenGL via iframe RPC or so. There isn't a clean way of calling (Objective-)C functions from JavaScript on iOS, unfortunately. Performance could be a problem.
- AOT-Compile or interpret the JavaScript in a third-party runtime, then implement WebGL from there. JIT compilers are disallowed on iOS, so something like V8 won't work. Appcelerator Titanium statically compiles JavaScript as far as I know, and also has an interpreter. You could use that, but you'd still need to implement the WebGL glue yourself.

I'm not aware of any existing WebGL bridges for iOS, so I think you *will* need to either write it yourself or get someone to do it for you. One problem that might not be possible to overcome is if you use anything other than WebGL to display stuff - e.g. HTML, 2D <canvas>, etc. Combining WebView display with an OpenGL framebuffer is going to be rather tricky.

I don't know much about Android, but considering the rules are more relaxed there, it might be possible to embed a WebGL-compatible browser there.

Comment: Is JIT really banned? I doubt it? I thought Apple just wanted to prevent a strong open platform being possible on top of their platform using open-ended scripting (with anyone able to develop cool 3D stuff etc without needing an Apple developer license).

Comment: Yes, JIT is banned by technical means. You can't mark memory pages as `PROT_EXEC` via `mprotect()` or `mmap()`. There is a special `MAP_JIT` flag that Safari uses, but this is enabled by a sandboxing entitlement, which Apple doesn't allow on 3rd party apps. So the upshot of this is you can't execute code generated at runtime. Note that this is distinct from the rule of not being allowed to *interpret* code downloaded from the network. (this is just an App Store rule, there's no way for the to OS to enforce it)

Comment: Thanks for the distinction. But aren't there kinds of JIT that are not blocked?

Comment: Generating executable machine code at runtime is the generally accepted definition JIT compilation, and that is covered by the `mmap()` restriction. I don't know what other "kind of JIT" you might be thinking of.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are any easy converter tools. You'll probably have to take your WebGL codebase and rewrite in OpenGL for both platforms, to create native apps.

Comment: That's opposite what he's asking. That is also obvious! The point is not to use OpenGL and use WebGL because then you can make websites and mobile apps all at the same time!

Comment: Yes, but I'm saying there are no such tools to do this. You are much better off coding natively.

Comment: Well he did mention that "middleware" is OK. Such a middleware is called PhoneGap. The only thing is you'll have to figure out how to take a webkit browser and enable webGL for it on Android and iPhone. Then you can use PhoneGap to write all the javascript-to-native code you want while using video acceleration at the same time. If I ever get free time from school I contemplate doing it.

Comment: is there chance to embed chrome beta view inside android app  to render webgl , or at least open via chrome beta ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not ready yet, but ForPlay may be able to act as a common development platform for Android and WebGL via GWT.

Comment: can you give link please ?

Answer (score 1):

Bundling WebKit and your app's resources (.js, textures, etc) into an iOS or Android application doesn't sounds too much difficult. I'm assuming that since Google and Apple are major contributors to the WebKit project, all the required support (for multitouch and other stuff) is already there.

PS: many iOS apps use interpreted Javascript or Lua. The rules are there to prevent your app to execute 3rd party code (esp from the internet), not the code you'd bundle in your own app.

**EDIT**: To clarify, I think you'd need to implement your own web view using webkit (built from source) in order to use WebGL *and* pass Apple's screening process, as activating WebGL in the Apple-provided web view will get your app rejected.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options to be able to deploy a native WebGL app. EjectaGL is a great WebGL implementation but a little bit harder to master (http://codehum.com/stuff/ejectagl/).

Another option is Ludei that recently announced their support for WebGL on both iOS and Android. It is easier to use and supports acceleration for HTML5 canvas in both 2D and 3D through WebGL. It also provides a way to monetize your app using IAPs, ads and plenty of extensions. It is much easier to test using the CocoonJS Launcher App and their cloud compiler.

www.ludei.com
http://blog.ludei.com/webgl-demos-arrive-to-google-play-store/

Answer (score -3):

Try [Phonegap](http://www.phonegap.com/). It allows you to build "native" HTML+CSS+JS apps using the standard Webkit installation on your OS. And it provides a javascript-to-native bridge to allow you to do things not possible in pure webapps.

Comment: Phonegap does not support WebGL, as it uses the platform's Webkit -- saw someone enabled WebGL in the Maemo version, but it doesn't seem that they have any plans to switch to their own Webkit for WebGL.

Comment: I think it'll be available soon enough!