# Is it possible to write a 3D game like 'Temple Run' without WebGL?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, cordova

iOS doesn't support WebGL yet, and I need to write a 3D-ish game like Temple Run for iOS. Is it possible to write a game like that in ordinary Canvas? Or should I give up on this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use native SDKs?

Comment: You can enable WebGL on current iOS versions, as I describe in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8954930/19679), but the performance is far slower than anything you'd do natively in OpenGL ES. I don't think it will catch up for quite a while, based on what I've seen.

Comment: Hey Brad, I thought a Temple run was developed on Unity3D. But apparently it was not. Any idea what framework was used for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I would not try to write a Temple Run like game running in a Canvas and wrapped in PhoneGap on iOS. There is an issue where Safari on iOS runs using the Nitro JavaScript engine which is quite fast but apps that use a UIWebView like PhoneGap are limited to using a slower version of the JavaScript interpreter. This causes problems when you are trying to write games like Temple Run.

You can write games in PhoneGap but the type of game you are talking about would really stretch the system to the max. I don't want to discourage you, I just want you to have the info.

Comment: Since Temple Run is listed as featured app on the PhoneGap site it must contain PhoneGap.

Comment: I don't believe Temple Run is listed as a featured app. You got a link to that?